# Finland's Universal Basic Income Test - how much in local terms?

Tags: data-request, welfare-economics

Finland is currently trialling UBI at a rate of €560 (£473) per month. I'm looking for some contextualization of this figure.

- Is this figure supposed to cover housing costs, or are they paid from a separate benefit for those who can't afford them? If not, what's the least one might pay for housing in Finland?
- How much does a week of food cost in Finland?

Comment: Social welfare in Sweden (with price levels similar to Finland) is 3930 SEK (ca 400 EUR) per month. That figure does not include rent, electricity and union membership.

Comment: Update: from asking my Finnish friend! Housing benefit is paid separately, and for some people could potentially (unlike UBI) be removed if they start work. Another complication is that benefits in Finland are taxed but the UBI trial isn't. So this isn't a perfect test of UBI, but you have to start somewhere; apparently this is phase 1 of a trial and it will be rolled out for other groups next year.